# In Powershell Script, how to convert '%5c' delimted CSV file to '/' delimited CSV file?

Tags: csv, powershell

I wrote a powershell script to retrive NAME & PATH of VM's(virtula machine) and save them in CSV file, But when ever there is '**/**' it displays as '**%5c**' i have no idea why its showing like that and I dont know how to change it.

Here is my powershell CODE:

```
function Get-Path{
        param($Object)

        $path = $object.Name
        $parent = Get-View $Object.ExtensionData.ResourcePool
        while($parent){
        $path = $parent.Name + "/" + $path

            if($parent.Parent){
                $parent = Get-View $parent.Parent
            }
            else{$parent = $null}
        }
        $path
    }

    Get-VM `
| Select Name, @{N="Path";E={(Get-Path -Object $_) -replace "^.*?Resources"}} `
| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
| Select-Object -Skip 1 `
| Set-Content -Path C:\izaz\test.csv
```

Comment: A side note: To simplify line breaking, you can break a line safely right after a pipe symbol. Like this: `Get-VM | <linebreak> Select... | <linebreak> ...`

Comment: Am totally new to Powershell and i dont know how to give the line break,
Can you give an example?

Comment: You should first check if `Get-Path` returns a correctly formatted string, that is, it does not have `%5C` already. If yes, change `"/"` to `'/'` (single quotes instead of double). Also check if specifying `$path` as `[String]` would do something to output.

Comment: A `<linebreak>` is just a placeholder for a line break in your text, because here comments do not support line breaks. ;)

Comment: but how to replace the '%5c' into '/'

Comment: You should discover how does `%5c` appear in the first place, are there any in your data, for example. Replacing is as simple as calling `$string -replace '%5c','/'`

Comment: i have no idea why does %5c is appearing and i dont have %5c in my path, Instead of '/' it displaying '%5c'

Comment: So, if you manually run `Get-Path -object (Get-VM)[0]` you receive a properly formatted string?

Comment: Am getting an error when i used `Get-Path -object (Get-VM)[0]`

Comment: Hmm, maybe `Get-Path -object ((Get-VM)[0])` then. The trick is to get the first VM returned by `Get-VM` and call `Get-Path` against it, and check what string is returned. If there's `%5c` in explicit, you've found the cause.

Comment: Where does i have to use this `Get-Path -object ((Get-VM)[0])` code

Comment: Add it as the last line of your Powershell script and review its output when you launch it via interactive Powershell. (And learn to debug, please)

Comment: Thanks for making a new question for this. I noticed in your other post that 2 of the output lines have that slash in there. One of the cmdlets here is having to deal with that character in an "escaped" form. If that character is a slash then restoring it would create the incorrect illusion of structure. `@{N="Path";E={(Get-Path -Object $_) -replace "^.*?Resources" -replace "%5c","/"}}` Maybe?